# Changing image of button while pressed in Racket

Tags: user-interface, racket

The way I have it set up right now makes it so that when the button is clicked the images swap. But the button image stays swapped after it has been clicked. How do I make it go back to the original image once I let go of the left click?

```
(define spin-img
    (read-bitmap "slot_machine/Bare Bones Slot Machine Frame/spin.png"))

(define spin-pressed-img
    (read-bitmap "slot_machine/Bare Bones Slot Machine Frame/spin_pressed.png"))

(define spin-button
    (new button% [parent panel] [label spin-img]
    [callback (lambda (button event)
        (send spin-button set-label spin-img-pressed)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick experiment, see code below, shows that you don't receive a button event when you left click on the button - you get an event when you release the mouse.

Try clicking the button and notice what and when the event is printed.
Also try clicking the button, moving the cursor outside the button and releasing.

```
#lang racket
(require racket/gui)

(define frame (new frame% [label "Example"]))
(define msg (new message% [parent frame]
                          [label "No events so far..."]))

(new button% [parent frame]
             [label "Click Me"]
             [callback (lambda (button event)
                         (displayln (list (send event get-event-type) 
                                          (send event get-time-stamp)))
                         (send msg set-label "Button click"))])

(send frame show #t)
```

If you want a clickable image that changes, maybe a small canvas is the solution?
A canvas can give you event both on mouse down and up.

Comment: I'm trying the small canvas method but I'm having trouble with drawing the bitmap into the paint-callback method. (lambda (canvas dc) (send dc draw-bitmap "img.png") (send dc flush). I'm flushing because the docs says "Drawing to a canvas’s drawing context actually renders into an offscreen buffer. The buffer is automatically flushed to the screen asynchronously, explicitly via the flush method," But I'm obviously doing something wrong.